# Laravel Header Request Doesn't Return Anything in Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Pengurus;
use Closure;
use Response;

class ApiAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $token = $request->header('APP_KEY');
        $validateToken = Pengurus::where('token',$token)->first();

        if(!$validateToken){
            return Response::json(['message'=>'Anda Belum Login, Silahkan Login Terlebih Dahulu'],401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------

how to fix it?
in localhost it's works, but when i try in cpanel it's doesn't work.

Comment: what's the error you get? do you have same dataabse on host as localhost? does your token exist in host database?

Comment: @mafortis hi, this is solved already

Comment: Same issue @mafortis does it works?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of PHP does not allow _ in the header please use

```
$token = $request->header('APP-KEY')
```

Answer (score -1):

Hy I have got the solution
remove _ for your key and bingo
like, replace APP_KEY with APPKEY and bingo.
Welcome in advance